# What are "General Quality Indicators" for scientific research?

Tags: mathematics, application, cv, bibliometrics

I am currently filling in a CV in the Spanish CVN online system (https://cvn.fecyt.es/).

In the section "Scientific and technological activities" it asks to specify "General Quality Indicators" in up to 3500 words.

I am a mathematician and I have never heard of such indicators, what are relevant things to put here? I.e., seminars organised, papers published?

A side question, at some point it refers to the h-index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index), have you ever seen this been used in mathematics?

TIA

Comment: Is this a general system for all fields, or specific to mathematics? (I don't understand Spanish). Often such general systems include things that are not really used by specific fields, in response to your side question on h-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seminars and papers are activities. They are asking to elaborate on the **quality** of such activities, preferably with some objective indicator. For instance, a seminar can be taught *by* *invitation* at an institution that occupies a *relevant* *place* in the Shanghai ranking of Universities. Or a paper can be published in a journal placed in the *first* *quartile* of its category sorted by impact factor.

The *h*-index is used pervasively in Spain and Mathematics is not an exception.

Good luck.

EDIT: What is your final goal when filling in the CV? You should find additional information on the specific call you apply to. For instance, if you are thinking about applying to accreditation (i.e. to pursue an assistant or tenure position) then you should have a look at the accreditation agency web site: [www.aneca.es](http://www.aneca.es)

Comment: That makes sense. I am applying for a research position and I guess in Maths you cannot really arrive at 3500 characters for this and definitely the h-index is not very relevant. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be direct a direct indication of what should be in the CV. Cheers for the answer by the way.

Comment: @MatteoVannacci It is not necessary to fiil in the full 3500 characters but at least you have some space to freely point out what you think is most significant from your CV. Think that evaluators have to read dozens of CVs, often from areas that are not directly related to their research. Then, it does not make a difference one paper more or less, but you can point out that some paper received a prize, or it is established as a reference in a very specialized topic or... whatever merit you think makes you stand out from the rest of candidates.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there a place where to write down talks given (and conferences attended) in the CVN?